# LaTeX report wrong error line when enclosing thing within a macro

Tags: macros, errors

I like to write my LaTeX C++ style

```
1 \mydisplay
2 {
3     \BoomUndefinedMacro \\
4     x + 1 = 2
5 }
```

But then LaTeX, LaTeX say that the error is in line 5, instead of line 3.
This is not useful, because in more involved use case, there are a hundred line in the display.

Is there a work around in writing enclosing macro so that LaTeX gives the right line number?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\mydisplay}[1]{\begin{align} #1 \end{align}}

\begin{document}

\mydisplay
{
    \boomUndefinedMacro \\
    x + 1 = 2
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When TeX reads an argument, it doesn't look whether the tokens are defined, so when it discovers the error it's already at the line where the closing brace is.

Comment: It depends on what your macro is supposed to do.  In rare cases, it is possible (e.g., making something bold can be done with `\def\mybold#{\bgroup\bf\let\bgroup=}`), but in general, egreg is right.  This is actually a good thing, bcause you wouldn't want TeX to complain when seeing `\boom` in `\newcommand{\boom}{...}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing you can really do. When TeX is absorbing an argument it doesn't expand macros or look whether they're defined. So when `\boomUndefinedMacro` is discovered, which happens at a later stage than absorbing the argument, TeX's reading apparatus is already at the line with the closing brace and that's the line it will show for the error.